# ADF: TempDb to user table very slow

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, sql-server-2019, wait-types, azure-data-factory

I have a Azure Data Factory Data Flow that writes ~250 Mio. rows (~100 GB) to a MS Sql Server 2019.

Currently, I have set the 'Use TempDB' option to true:
[image]

The first part of the job, i.e. writing all the data to the temporary table is fairly quick (~2h). As I can see in the activity monitor, it then basically copies to data from the temp-table into the target table.
However, this part is incredibly slow (taking several days). Checking the activity monitor and logs, it seems like the responsible task gets suspended all the time due to a `PAGEIOLATCH_SH` wait.

Additionally, to avoid a bottleneck due to writing logs, the recovery mode is set to `SIMPLE`.
The SQL server + database was freshly set up just for this task, so there are no other running/interfering tasks. How comes that it runs into these `PAGEIOLATCH_SH` constantly?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

### waiting

PAGEIOLATCH_SH is SQL Server reading pages from disk into memory. Since no reasonable database works with data on disk, the best way to reduce this wait is generally to have more memory available for SQL Server to cache data pages in.

You mentioned the table being ~100GB in size, so you'd need *over* that to fully avoid the waits. You'll also need to account for whatever other data is stored there, too.

Don't fall for people telling you this is a disk subsystem issue. You will hit PAGEIOLATCH_SH *whenever* you go to disk, not just when it's slow. Based on you spending *days* waiting on it, your server is probably teeny-tiny.

- [Compensating For Disk Waits In SQL Server](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/starting-sql-compensating-for-disk-waits/)
- [Signs You Need More Memory In Your SQL Server](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/signs-you-need-more-memory-in-your-sql-server/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That might be part of the problem, right now the machine has 32GB RAM. However, how comes that writing to tempDB is that fast nonetheless? Furthermore, I would guess that for a simple copy of the table from tempDB to a user table it would read the table page by page sequentially without resulting in many page swaps? Or is this assumption completely wrong?